# Subtracting values form each other in a StringBuffer

Tags: java, math, subtraction, stringbuffer

I have String Buffer with a list of values. I want to subtract each value in the string buffer from the first value in the string buffer `myValues.charAt(1) = 600;`. I'm looking for a very simple way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: you can parse them to integer and subtract...

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder

Comment: is a string builder easier to use Peter?